# ssh-keygen from Ed25519 OpenSSL pem private key

Tags: ssh, pem, ssh-keygen, ed25519

I would like to generate a public SSH key from an OpenSSL generated Ed25519 private key.

I tried:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ed25519_key -y > ed25519_ssh.pub
```

And got the error:

```
Load key "ed25519_key": invalid format
```

Answer (score -1):

SSH and SSL are two things.

`SSH` means *"Secure Shell"* and is used for remotely connecting to another machine to issue commands, most likely via a CLI (Command Line Interface).

`SSL` means *"Secure Sockets Layer"*, an older version of actual TLS, used to secure data transmission on a network.

I don't think you can create a **public SSH key** from an **OpenSSL generated Ed25519 private key**.

To create ed25519 SSL keys you can use `openssl`:

```bash
openssl genpkey -algorithm ed25519 -outform PEM -out ed25519_ssl.prv
openssl pkey -in ed25519_ssl.prv -pubout -out ed25519_ssl.pub
```

Edit: I might be wrong, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37313488/1563072)